# Retrieve a list of top ten highest points on Earth

Tags: sparql, point, wikidata, highest

I need to retrieve a list of top ten highest points on Earth using SPARQL on Wikidata

```
SELECT ?mountain ?mountainLabel WHERE {
  ?mountain wdt:P31 wd:Q8502.
  OPTIONAL { ?mountain wdt:P610 ?highest_point. }  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 10
```

I expect the output to be `mountain QIDs` in the first column, names of the `mountains` in the second column, and `heights` in the third column

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered before or it was in the Wikidata examples

Comment: Ah, here we go: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Mountains

Comment: I don't have a answer, that is why I am asking for help.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?mountainLabel ?elev 
{
   ?mountain wdt:P31 wd:Q8502 ;
         p:P625/psv:P625/wikibase:geoGlobe wd:Q2 ;
          wdt:P2044 ?elev
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
}
}
ORDER BY DESC(?elev)
limit 10`

Comment: `order by` takes ages because there are `309110` mountains in the dataset and currently the endpoints seems to be slow.

Comment: Apparently, some mountains have elevation values in different units, thus, to stick e.g. to meters you should do: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item  ?elev ?unit{ 
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q8502 ; 
            p:P625/psv:P625/wikibase:geoGlobe wd:Q2 ; 
            p:P2044/psv:P2044                   ?valuenode.
  ?valuenode wikibase:quantityAmount     ?elev ;
              wikibase:quantityUnit       wd:Q11573
#SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 
                                           } 
ORDER BY DESC(?elev)
limit 10`